# Getting text from <a> href link using beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I've been trying to make a generic method so that I'm able to parse in any URL and Classes;
They have been successful but for now I'd like to gather data from the text; instead of the title. Etc: **"Xiaomi 70Mai Pro"**

I've tried referencing from these two sources; but I'm still unsure...

1. [WebScraper-Sample](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39507/error-in-python-while-scrapping-data-from-indeedattributeerror-str-object-ha)
2. [Parse HTML Table for URL, Place into List](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3majtq/beautifulsoup_parse_html_table_for_url_place_into/)

   ```
    links = 'SampleLink... with table cell'

    def getURLData(url):  # scrape data from Link
    try:
        page = requests.get(url)
        content = page.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
        return soup
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error.getURLData:', e)
        return None


    inputLink = getURLData(links)


    def tableCheck():  # if there's a table cell;
    data = []
    for table_tag in inputLink.find_all('td', {'class': 'row1'}):
        topic_title = table_tag.find('a', href=True)
        if topic_title:
            datum = {'topic_title': topic_title['title']}
            data.append(datum)
    return data


    print(tableCheck())
   ```

this was the output

```
  {'topic_title': 'This topic was started: Dec 6 2018, 12:20 PM'}, 
  {'topic_title': 'This topic was started: Nov 19 2018, 10:30 AM'}, 
  {'topic_title': 'This topic was started: Nov 28 2018, 09:16 PM'},
  {'topic_title': 'This topic was started: Oct 3 2018, 11:10 AM'},
```

this is the cell i'm trying to extract data from; I've tried to use the `topic_title = table_tag.find('a', href=True).text` but I really doubt that would work; I'm still not so exposed with BeautifulSoup and I'm kind of stuck thinking how would I get the data; do I try another for loop? to extract the data within it?

```
<td class = "row1" valign = "middle" >
   <div >
        <div style = "float:left" >
           <a href = "/topic/4667583" title = "This topic was started: Oct 3 2018, 
            11:10 AM" > 
           Xiaomi 70Mai Pro < /a >
        </div >
        <br >
    </div >
    </td
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the existing answer, the only modification you need to make is *add the link text to your dictionary*:

```
topic_title = table_tag.find('a', href=True)
if topic_title:
    datum = {
        'topic_title': topic_title['title'], 
        'topic_text': topic_title.text
    }
    data.append(datum)
```

Comment: Oh wow; it was such a simple solution that it skipped my mind. I was on the right path; just doing it in a really dumb way. Thank you so much ~ fixed the problem <3